# ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 issue with SQL loader and TOAD

Tags: sql, sql-loader

I am trying to load data to 'LOAN' table. Data is position-format text file is  20190512. when I changed column type to varchar2(8 char), data got loaded but when I am using TO_Date or Date function to load after changing it's type to DATE column type, I'm getting below mentioned error

ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Note: This column has no data at the positions at this moment.

I've tried "TO_DATE(:DR430_LAST_MOD_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')" and Date and none of it seems to work. However, similar, to_Date syntax is working for other date columns. Also, This column, in focus, has no data at the positions at this moment.

DR430_LAST_MOD_DATE      POSITION (7404:7411)  DATE "YYYYMMDD" NULLIF (DR430_LAST_MOD_DATE = BLANKS), --please suggest what to write after position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove empty spaces before converting to date

```sql
TO_DATE(TRIM(:DR430_LAST_MOD_DATE), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: I agree.  Oracle will react badly if you try to convert 8 space characters to a date but an empty string will be treated as NULL.

Comment: Could you please let me know if  "TO_DATE(TRIM(:DR430_LAST_MOD_DATE), 'YYYYMMDD') , nullif TRIM(:DR430_LAST_MOD_DATE) = BLANKS" is correct? I am not able to pass to_date without " " and don't know how to add nullif condition in it inside " " after to_date. I am super new to sql loader.

Comment: Just trim the data you wish to convert and oracle will take care of changing it to null if it's an empty string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt help!

Comment: @AndréSanson: May I ask totally separate question of how to load only top 5 or 10 rows using sql loader. Since I am super new to this, It'll be great if you can share the condition. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SachinSharma Sorry, my knowledge in sql loader is minimal and I can't help you with that.